# Why my code for adding a new user is not working, and it only reads the code for checking if ID is existing on database?

Tags: c#

When I'm trying to add a new user on the database, it's only reading the code on checking the ID if it's existing on the database. What should I do with my code?

I haven't try other codes yet because I'm having trouble on finding one, so any help will greatly appreciated.

```cs
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtSupID.Text == "" || txtName.Text == "" || txtAddress.Text == "" || txtContactNum.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill out the required fields", "Required", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    }
    else
    {
        string checkID = "SELECT SupplierID FROM Suppliers WHERE SupplierID = @SupplyID";
        cmd.CommandText = checkID;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SupplyID", txtSupID.Text);
        adapt.InsertCommand = cmd;
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        adapt.Fill(ds);
        int i = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

        if (i > 0)
        {
            ds.Clear();
            MessageBox.Show("Supplier ID " + txtSupID.Text + " already exist", "Invalid", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
            MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open();

                string insert = "INSERT INTO Suppliers (SupplierID, Name, Address, ContactNumber, Email, Notes) VALUES(@SID,
@name, @address, @contactnum, @email, @notes)";
cmd.CommandText = insert;

                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SID", txtSupID.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtName.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txtAddress.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contactnum", txtContactNum.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtEmail.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@notes", txtNotes.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                GetData();

                dtgSuppliers.Refresh();

                MessageBox.Show("Successfully added a new Supplier", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                ClearAll();

                con.Close();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you clear the parameters collection before calling the adapter Fill method? By the way, you are setting the InsertCommand in the adapter, but you should set the SelectCommand instead

Comment: The reason why I put a code to clear the parameters, because I'm getting a message that my parameter for the ID (@SupplyID) has been declared. But I will try to change the command for the adapter and I will update you if it works. Thanks!

Comment: You have a serious problem here. You should never use global objects like an SqlConnection, SqlCommand, SqlDataAdapter and so on. You should declare them when you need them and start using the _using statement_ around those disposable objects. Keeping them around for the lifetime of your application is not a good practice

Comment: Thanks for the advise, really appreciate it. By the way, I try changing the adapter command to SelectCommand and I got an error on the code `adapt.Fill(ds);` and it says "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Must declare the scalar variable "@SupplyID".'"

Comment: I was able now to address my issue with my code. I removed the code `cmd.Parameters.Clear();` under the check id code and it's now adding the data. Thanks for your time and I will surely study the _using Statement_ for me to use it in my future applications.